# How to express sample space

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have been given

$$P(A\mid B) = P(A)$$
$$P(C\mid D) < P(C)$$
$$P(E\mid F) > P(E)$$

and have been asked to give an example of  a sample space. My question is how can I go about expressing a sample space with this information?  I am unsure of where to begin with this question and would like general hints or instructions on how to do this.

No answers though please!

Comment: I think it is less a matter of expressing a sample space in terms of this information, but rather to make up a sample space, label some of the subsets of that space $A, B, C, D, E, F$, and then show the given statements of the probabilities are true. At least that is my guess what was wanted; maybe it would help to copy a larger part of the original question.

Comment: This is the entire original question

Comment: I was hoping you did not receive a written question saying, "I &hellip; have been asked to give an example of a sample space." It seems more likely that the question actually contained the first sentence of Graham Kemp's answer, followed by the three formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an example of any sample space containing six events such that you can affirm that those three probability statements are true.

Hint: what do those statements say about the dependence of each pair of events?

Comment: Alright so for example, I can conclude from P(A|B) = P(A) that A and B are independent events. Therefore can I write out the sample space for A and B as {A, B}? Then how could this be applied to the second case?

Comment: or as {$A \cap B + A \cap \bar{B}$}

Comment: @theGuy05  I suggest first picking a space for your example, such as rolling several dice, a series of coin tosses, or whatever, and *then* pick events $A$ to $E$ that fit the equations.

Comment: @theGuy05 I hope your book or instructor showed at least one example of something called a "sample space" before asking you to create one of your own; also that they showed at least one example of an event that was not just a single element of its sample space. For example, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is a sample space corresponding to rolling a single die once; $A=\{2,4,6\}$ is the event that an even number is rolled. Or perhaps they used a different notation; that would be fine, as long as there were some suitable examples to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Translating into an intuitive language, the first one means that it would not change the likelihood of $A$ whether you know $B$ occured. As for the second and third ones, the new information you acquired (namely, $D$ and $F$) forces you to update your calculations.

Now consider a die rolling scenario.